# Is there a Drupal module that implements a (+/-) button with a counter textbox at the side?

Tags: forms

Can you implement a (+/-) button with a counter textbox at the side with Drupal like a shown below?

[image]

A very simple way of implementing this, like using an existing module, is much welcome. I am also open for answers implementating this using hard coded scripts.

Comment: Yes. But what do you want? [`<input type="number">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29) is not enough?

Comment: No actually, I wan't to add a button for increment and decrement.

Comment: That's what number input is supposed to be displayed.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr Oh... wouldn't that be "[implementing a functionality for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" - as in the **not** section?

Comment: I am also open for any implementation using hard coded scripts, but for a simpler way of implementing it like an existing module is much welcome.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr if OP needs a module, we need more data. How can we know which of these he needs: entity field, form api field, webform field, standalone voting module? Or possibly others with similar look?

Answer (score 3):

There is already a module that gives you a vote up/down button, just like the one we have here on SE: https://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down.

> Allows votes on some drupal entities and provides the base for implementing votes on other entities.

It is still under dev for Drupal 7, but IMHO quite usable.  If you find any problems, it will probably be less work to help the developers fix those, compared to reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

In your existing form(or if one does not exist, you need to create it), add a textfield like this, with some associated markup:

```
$form['counter'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield', 
  '#title' => t('Counter value'), 
  '#default_value' => YOUR DEFAULT VALUE CALCULATED BY REQUIRED LOGIC GOES HERE, MAKE SURE ITS INTEGER, 
  '#size' => 30, 
  '#maxlength' => 128, 
  '#attributes' => array('class' => 'counter-textfield'),
  '#suffix' => '<div class="counter-wrapper"><div class="vote-up"></div><div class="vote-down"></div></div>',
);
```

Now in JS file, apply this code:

```
Drupal.behaviors.updown = { attach: function (context, settings) { 
      $('.vote-up').click(function() {
        var existing = $('.counter-textfield input').val();
        var new_count = parseInt(existing) + parseInt(1);
        if(new_count < 0) {
          new_count = 0;
        }
        $('.counter-textfield input').val(new_count);
      });

      $('.vote-down').click(function() {
        var existing = $('.counter-textfield input').val();
        var new_count = parseInt(existing) - parseInt(1);
        if(new_count < 0) {
          new_count = 0;
        }
        $('.counter-textfield input').val(new_count);
      });
    } 
};
```

Comment: Does anybody know if there is a module for this too? Thanks.

Comment: I have seen  the Stepper Field Module. https://www.drupal.org/project/field_stepper which I find very helpful. Thank you.